# on click disable function, else function works?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery code here:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $("td").click(function (e) {
        var chk = $(this).closest("tr").find("input:checkbox").get(0);

        if (e.target != chk) {
            chk.checked = !chk.checked;
        }

        if ($(this).closest("tr").find("input:checkbox").is(":checked")) {
            $(this).closest("tr").css("font-weight", "bold");
        } else {
            $(this).closest("tr").css("font-weight", "");
        }
    });
});
```

As you can see I have a lot of checkboxes and on click on any `td` it's checked and adding css.

It works fine. What I want, is in the same form I also have a lot of `select` boxes.
When I try to choose something the function works.
I want to disable the function on click on the select box because I want to choose not to enable the checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just check if the target is a select or anything inside a select element, like options :

```
$(function () {
    $("td").on('click', function (e) {
        if (! $(e.target).closest('select').length ) {
           var tr  = $(this).closest("tr"),
               chk = tr.find("input[type='checkbox']").get(0);
           if (e.target != chk) {
               chk.checked = !chk.checked;
           }
           if ( tr.find("input[type='checkbox']").is(":checked")) {
               tr.css("font-weight", "bold");
           } else {
               tr.css("font-weight", "");
           }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to test what the mouse clicked, and if it was the , then don't change the checkbox, correct?

You should be able to get that from the event's properties. For example:

```
if (!$('#' + e.target.id).hasClass('mySelectBox')){
  //your code...
}
```

There might be a more succinct way, I haven't tested, but try this:

```
if (e.target != 'select'){
  //your code..
}
```

**Update:** Yeah, what @adeneo said!